# SQL Server table relationship

Tags: sql-server, database

I have to create a database that have flat, flat owner, tenant and bills tables etc.

The question is when the tenant or flat owner delays bill payment, there will be a %5 extra tax due to delay. First of all I have to create the tables correctly and have to write functions to return the flat, flat owner, tenant (if exists) and the total bill amount with delay tax (if any).

In final exam I did a table diagram something like this and I failed the exam.

[image: table relationship diagram]

I'm asking you to make correct tables and the query that I asked above. Thank you.

Comment: Consider that your schema can't possibly support all the rules. You need to charge an additional 5% when the payment is late. With your schema you have no way of knowing anything about when a payment was made as there is no date column anywhere. I would think the monthly rent amount belongs in the Flat table, then you need some way to know when the payment is due. That could maybe always be the first of the month. But you still need to know when a payment is made. It seems you probably want at least one more table here for payments.

Answer (score 0):

1. **About DB Structure**

You can better draw the diagram based on requirements. It will be easy once the concept of relationships is clear to you

**For Example:**

- Assume a flat can have only 1 owner but an owner can own more than 1
  flats. This is a 1:M relationship and will be implemented by using
  owner's primary key as foreign key in Flat Table
- Similary A flat can have multiple tenants and a tenant can have rented multiple flats(Based on your requirement). This is a M:N relationship and can be implemented by using a bridge table containing both tables primary key as foreign key
- A bill will be unique to each flat but a flat can have multiple bills. This is also 1:M as first case.

for more help on RDBMS Relations you can find good explanation here [Designing a Relational Database and Creating an Entity Relationship Diagram](https://towardsdatascience.com/designing-a-relational-database-and-creating-an-entity-relationship-diagram-89c1c19320b2)

2. **Bill Charges Maintenance**
   You can add fieds in your bill table such as due_date, extra_Tax_percentage and extra_Tax_amount to perform various operations and keep record